# How to get the dynamic button's id ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to find a way to send the id of the clicked button to the backend. The problem is that I am creating lots of buttons with one method but the id is different.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.showManager.GetMovies())
            {
                i++;
                @if (Model.user.IsAdmin == true)
                {
                            <input class="btn_confirm" type="submit" id=i value="Delete"/>
                }
            }
```

The point is that every button is created with different id and I want to send that id to the backend.

Comment: You can do that, should get all the `IDS` while submitting the form value.

Comment: Just copy and paste my code first. Then watch how it works, then modify as per your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

My demo is a MVC project, I have a DynamicButtonController and a Index view:

DynamicButtonController:

```
 public class DynamicButtonController : Controller
{
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
     }
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index(int id)
     {
       return View();
      }
 }
```

Index view :

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 5;i++ )
{             
 <input class="btn_confirm" type="submit" id=@i value="Delete"  />              
            }
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".btn_confirm").click(function()
{  
     var data = (this).id;

$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/DynamicButton/Index/',
           data: { id: data }  
       });
});
</script>
```

result:
[image]

If you use **Razor pages**, you can refer to the below demo,use `asp-route-id="@i"`

ButtonIdModel:

```
public class ButtonIdModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }     
        public void OnPost(string id)
        {

        }
    }
```

ButtonId.cshtml:

```
@page
@model yourproject.Pages.ButtonIdModel
<form  method="post">
@for (var i = 0; i < 5;i++ )
{             
 <input  class="btn_confirm" type="submit" id=@i value="Delete"  asp-route-id="@i" />   
 
}
 </form>
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it doesn't work and doesn't even go into the Index method. Is there something to do with the foreach?

Comment: @Venoz this is a demo about how to get the id of the button, you just need to add ajax code to pass your id(use your  url ), my `for` is just to display button.

Comment: @Venoz Try to use `F12` to is any error message in the console.

Comment: @Venoz Have you already  created lots of buttons with one method but the id is different? Do you use `F12` see the id  ?

Comment: @Venoz "doesn't even go into the Index method' Do you write the submit in the form? If so, you can add code like `$(".btn_confirm").click(function(e)
{   e.preventDefault();...` to have a try.

Comment: It doesn't work. Could you send me a demo of your project, maybe it would be easier to me

Comment: @Venoz Please see my update, a mvc and razor demo.

Answer (score 0):

> The point is that every button is created with different id and I want
> to send that id to the backend.

Well, based on your issue, you want to bind all the button `ids` then want to pass those `Ids` in your backend.

However, another answer has guided you how to pass id to your `controller`. Nonetheless, it doesn't resolve your main concern that is how to pass the list of ids on button submit.

**Algorithm:**

As said earlier, first you have to get the list of button ids which has been generated from your `foreach` loop and you have to push them in an array, finally need to pass those in your controller (backend). Here, importantly you have to keep in mind, it doesn't matter how the button been generated, `for loop` or `foreach` loop the fact is your button should have class name of same type and the `ids` for instance: `class="myBtnClass btn btn-danger"` and `id="btnId:@i"`

**Solution:**

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ViewGetDynamicButtonsID";
}


<div>
    @for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <input class="myBtnClass btn btn-danger" id="btnId:@i" value="Delete:@i" style="margin-bottom:2px" /> <br />
    }

    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
                var ids = [];
                $(".myBtnClass").each(function () {
                    //Getting All Button Ids and Pusing in array
                    ids.push($(this).attr("id"));
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:5094/stuff/GetAllButtonId',
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: { buttonids: ids },
                    success: function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                        alert("It works")
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("It failed");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult CreateDynamicButton()// This is for loading the view
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetAllButtonId(List<string> buttonids) // This for submit the button request. 
        {
            return Ok(buttonids);
        }
```

**Note:** I have defined `Button Ids` as `List<string>` thus you can do it as your `convenient type`

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I tried the same as you but again it doesn't even trigger the methods in the back-end. Also I cannot use View() and Ok() instead I can use this.Page()

Comment: Could you please share your code, so that can be seen what's wrong with it. However, What I shown is that you are looking for?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KjLfwUC2 here is the code to both View and Controller. I pasted it in that site because I cannot paste it here.

Comment: You have done few mistakes, firstly,  `<input class="myBtnClass btn btn-danger" id="btnId:@i" value="Delete:@i" runat="server" />`, this is `runat="server"` incorrect in asp.net core . Secondly, you haven't modified your code, your button class name is `class="btn_confirm"` But in the `submit function` you have set `btnSubmit` and not calling it by Id. You are in mess here. So either call it by ID or by class if class then use like this : btn_confirm in  $(".btn_confirm ").on("click", function (). By the way what your expectations?

Comment: https://gifyu.com/image/SErfX now this is the problem. I have no clue what's going on as I dont understand JS at all

Comment: I cannot see the image very foggy it is.